# Foundation datepicker is not working while used in the ajax call response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datepicker, zurb-foundation

I am using foundation datepicker In that I have a problem that the text box does not show the datepicker.

```
if (courseflag == "Y") {
    _SubDocumentHtml = _SubDocumentHtml + "<div class='row'><table>" +
        "<thead>" +
        "<tr>" +
            "<th>Course started year:" +
            "<input type='text'  name='dpcourse_start' id='dpcourse_start' data-date-format='dd/mm/yyyy'>" +
            "</th>" +
            "<th>Course completion year:" +
               "<input type='text' name='dpcourse_end' id='dpcourse_end' data-date-format='dd/mm/yyyy'>" +
            "</th>" +
        "</tr>" +
        "</thead>" +
    "</table></div>"
}
```

In the document.ready function I have used

```
$('#dpcourse_start').fdatepicker({
    format: 'dd-mm-yyyy'
});
$('#dpcourse_end').fdatepicker({
    format: 'dd-mm-yyyy'
});
```

But still the date picker does not shown.Please help me friends.

Comment: Hi, please make jsfiddle, it will be easier to help you

Comment: Use the selectors without the method and see if you have object returned or undefined, if it is undefined then something with the way you are apending the new element is off